# Writing more better SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query here that's painfully slow. Part of the problem may be that tableA in the sub-query has a quite substantial size in comparison to the other tables.

**TABLES STRUCTURE**

```
*-------------------*------------------*-------------------*
|     ID_TABLE      |    DATA_TABLE    |  DATA_TABLE_EXT   |
*-------------------*------------------*-------------------*
| id              n<|>1 id           1<|>n owner_id        |
| foreign_id        |   owner_id       |   information     |
| foreign_id_source |   date_field     |   ...             |
| ...               |  ...             |                   |
*-------------------*------------------*-------------------*
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT ID_TABLE.foreign_id_source, count(ID_TABLE.id) as count 
FROM DATA_TABLE
LEFT JOIN ID_TABLE ON DATA_TABLE.id = ID_TABLE.id
WHERE DATA_TABLE.owner_id = 'some_id'
AND DATA_TABLE.date_field > 'some_date'
AND DATA_TABLE.id IN (
                SELECT DATA_TABLE_EXT.owner_id FROM DATA_TABLE_EXT
                JOIN DATA_TABLE ON DATA_TABLE_EXT.owner_id = DATA_TABLE.id
                WHERE DATA_TABLE.owner_id = 'some_id'
                GROUP BY DATA_TABLE.id
                HAVING SUM(ABS(DATA_TABLE_EXT.information)) <> 0
            )
GROUP BY ID_TABLE.foreign_id_source
ORDER BY count ASC
```

**REQUIRED RESULT**

```
*-------------------*-------------*
| foreign_id_source |    count    |
*-------------------*-------------*
|  source1          |     45      |
|  source2          |     10      |
|  ...              |             |
*-------------------*-------------*
```

Each id in DATA_TABLE may have multiple records in ID_TABLE.
many records in DATA_TABLE may have the same owner_id.

I'm looking for the number of records in data_table with a foreign_id_source, grouped by that foreign_id_source, where the record is after 'some_date' and it's DATA_TABLE_EXT records do not all have a value of 0 in the information field.

Short of creating indexes or other database manipulation is there a way to improve this query in terms of performance?

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Indexes? Got any? If so Where?

Comment: MySQL is notoriously poor at optimizing `WHERE field IN (SELECT ...)`. Use a `JOIN` instead.

Comment: It's usually wrong to `GROUP BY` a column in the `LEFT JOIN` table. This will group all the rows that have no match together in the result. You should `GROUP BY x.fieldI` instead of `GROUP BY i.fieldI`.

Comment: @Bamar I tried using a `JOIN` but it returns an incorrect result, but noted thank you.

Comment: You may need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the subquery when you join with it, to prevent multiplying the count.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The question mentions his foreign keys, they automatically get indexed.

Comment: @Barmar updated the question, should be clearer

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that query? Why are you adverse to indexes? Were all the foreign keys declared as foreign keys (and thus indexed)?

Comment: @Schwern, I'm not averse, I know indexes can make it run faster, I want to know if I can improve my code in other ways as well

Comment: `HAVING SUM(ABS(DATA_TABLE_EXT.information)) <> 0` This implies that at least one record has `DATA_TABLE_EXT.information <>0` -->> you don't need to sum the whole group to detect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is: `SUM(ABS(DATA_TABLE_EXT.information)) <> 0` can only be true if **at least one** `DATA_TABLE_EXT.information` is non-zero. So we don't have to `sum()` them, we only only need to check if a non-zero one exists.

[ I don't know if mysql is smart enough to handle the `exists()`, but in theory it is cheaper, and can be faster]

---

```
SELECT it.foreign_id_source, count(it.id) as count 
FROM DATA_TABLE dt
LEFT JOIN ID_TABLE it ON dt.id = it.id
WHERE dt.owner_id = 'some_id'
AND dt.date_field > 'some_date'
AND EXISTS ( 
        SELECT *
        FROM DATA_TABLE_EXT x
        JOIN DATA_TABLE dt2 ON x.owner_id = dt2.id
        WHERE x.id =dt.id
        AND dt2.owner_id = 'some_id'
        AND x.information <> 0
        )
GROUP BY it.foreign_id_source
ORDER BY count ASC
        ;
```

Comment: This does indeed bring back the value I'm looking for, thanks :).
And is faster than the original query.

Comment: It will need exactly the same keys and indexes. But probably fewer rows.

Comment: Noting that this is faster than using the join.
Seems like using a `INNER JOIN` can exhibit the same performance as an `EXISTS` if you're joining on a unique column, however if that is not the case then `EXISTS` will provide better performance

Comment: Ran this against production this morning. Improvement from 51.6s on the original query to 3.49s using this.

Answer (score 0):

Often moving the subquery to the `FROM` will help:

```
SELECT ID_TABLE.foreign_id_source, count(DATA_TABLE.id) as count 
FROM ID_TABLE LEFT JOIN
     DATA_TABLE
     ON DATA_TABLE.id = ID_TABLE.id JOIN
     (SELECT DATA_TABLE.id
      FROM DATA_TABLE_EXT JOIN
           DATA_TABLE
           ON DATA_TABLE_EXT.owner_id = DATA_TABLE.id
      WHERE DATA_TABLE.owner_id = 'some_value'
      GROUP BY DATA_TABLE.id
      HAVING SUM(ABS(DATA_TABLE_EXT.information)) <> 0
     ) xx
     ON DATA_TABLE.id = xx.id
WHERE DATA_TABLE.owner_id = 'some_value' AND
      DATA_TABLE.date_field > 'some_date'
GROUP BY x.field1
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

Then, you can think about indexes.  These would be `tableX(field2, fieldZ, field1, fieldX)`, `tableI(field1)`, tableX(field2, field1, fieldB)`, and`tableA(field1)`.

Comment: He said he got an incorrect result when he tried this. You probably need `SELECT DISTINCT a.field1` to prevent that.

Comment: @Barmar . . . I don't see how this could be returning duplicates from the subquery.   Consider `a.field1` in the subquery `select` (which I changed to `x.field1`).  The join condition means it is the same as `x.field1`, and this is the column used for grouping.  It should already be unique.

Comment: to clarify a bit more why this fails.
joining on tableI seems to mess with how the `GROUP BY` functions as it's seeing more rows than it should do.

Comment: x.field1 is the incorrect thing to select, looking for i.fieldI :) that field is unique among all tables.

Comment: @CorneliusJEhmke As I mentioned above, it's usually wrong to be selecting and grouping on a column that comes from a `LEFT JOIN`ed table. This column will be `NULL` for all the rows in `tableX` that don't have a match in `tableI`, so you'll merge all those rows together in the count.

Comment: @CorneliusJEhmke You should put your data model in the question instead of supplying it bit-by-bit in the comments. Oh, and in most cases, EXISTS() is the answer.

Comment: @wildplasser I'm not the owner of the data model, but noted :)

Comment: @CorneliusJEhmke `field1 is the same value across the tables as a foreign key | field2 is also a foreign key in tableX and is the value that the function that creates this query gets passed` -->> This is completely unreadable. Just show the DDL (plus some cardinality data) in the question. You need not be the owner, but you can describe it.